# suppress header in output of sybase query in Linux

Tags: sybase

Could someone tell me how to suppress header in the output of sybase query in Linux?

My output is like this:

```
col1 col2
---------
val11 val12
val21 val22
```

My required format is:

```
val11 val12
val21 val22
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-b` to suppress headers when you connect via isql.

```
isql -UmyUser -SMYSERVER -iscriptFile -b
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting.  I forget sometimes that answers should have a little more to them to accommodate a wider range of users.